# How to register a 64 bit out-of-process COM component for 64 AND 32 bit clients?

Tags: delphi, com, 64-bit

I have a Delphi XE4 application, which can act as an out-of-process COM component.
The application is sometimes started as 32 and sometimes as 64 bit application on the same computer.

The currently running instance should act as out-of-process server for a 32 bit COM client. The application registers[1] itself as "per user" COM component during start. Later the 32 bit COM client can connect to the running instance.

- This works fine for the 32 bit version of the application.
- This also works fine for the 64 bit version as long as only the 64 bit version is registered[2].
- This doesn't work anymore for the 64 bit version if the 32 bit version is registered too[3]. In this case the COM client always try to start a 32 bit application instead of using the running 64 bit instance.

**Is there a way for a 64 bit Delphi application to register itself for both 64 and 32 bit clients?**

(Editing the registry directly doesn't seem a good idea, but I imagine that at the end the 64 bit application should have removed the 32 bit version from the Wow6432Node branch or should have replaced it there).

*Notes*:

[1] = Code used by the application to registers itself during start:

```
ComServer.PerUserRegistration := True;
ComServer.UpdateRegistry(True);
ComServer.Initialize;
```

[2] Only 64 bit registered = path to the 64 bit exe can be found under HKCR/CLSID/{...}/LocalServer32 and there is nothing or a non existing path under HKCR/**Wow6432Node**/CLSID/{...}/LocalServer32

[3] 32 bit registered too = path to the 32 bit exe can be found under HKCR/**Wow6432Node**/CLSID/{...}/LocalServer32

Comment: I think you are meant to use stub proxy DLLs for this purpose. I did not read the question closely enough and stupidly thought you were dealing with in-proc COM DLLs. But in any case, how can your executable hope to write to `HKCR`? Is it going to write to the `HKCU` hive? Or are you expecting your executable to run elevated all the time? Are you sure you don't need install time registration?

Comment: @David Heffernan: HKCR is a mix of keys from HKCU and HKLM. And using "per user" registration I actually suppose that it is written in a part of the registry where the user is allowed to write. But anyway I would prefer avoid writing directly in the registry. I would prefer to use Delphi or Windows functions, that hide all the stuff with the registry. It's just useful to have a look at the registry during debugging to see what happens behind the scene. An I'm sure I don't need install time registration, it is the point of the "per user" registration!

Comment: @David Heffernan: And I don't see the point about the stub proxy DLLs. This would be useful for an in-process component. But as I wrote (even in the title of the question) I'm using out-of-process so it is not a problem to mix 32 and 64 bit. The only problem is about the registration.

Comment: How does your executable unregister itself? Since you have chosen the COM registration method that uses the registry, you need to consider that. I honestly don't see that you can expect to write values to the registry and not use an installer. Perhaps registration free COM is really what you are looking for.

Comment: More precisely: "The only problem is about the registration of the 64 bit version for the 32 bit client". I don't need registration free COM. It's working just fine in several cases. The application can unregister itself on exit. Sometimes it don't, because the 32 bit version often goes out of memory and just crash. But it wouldn't matter if only the 64 bit version could overwrite the registration of the 32 bit version during its start.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52689/discussion-between-name-and-david-heffernan)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I should say that I remain unconvinced of the wisdom of having your COM server register itself rather than having an installer do so. However, you have clearly stated that is your goal so let us proceed on that basis.

It looks to me as though you want the running application to write to both 32 and 64 bit views of the registry. I personally would write there directly. Use `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` and `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flags to access the 32 and 64 bit views of the registry.

In the comments and in chat, you indicate that you regard direct registry writes as hacking. But that is the officially documented way to register COM servers. And that is of course all that `UpdateRegistry` does. Since you have special requirements that are not handled by `UpdateRegistry` I cannot see a better way to achieve your goals.

Comment: Good point about KEY_WOW64_32KEY and KEY_WOW64_64KEY, I didn't know about them, it simplify a little bit writing directly to the registry. But I would still prefer to avoid it and that is exactly why I posted this question: to ask what possibilities are available to me.

Comment: You just need a single function to do the registry work and pass in the flag to be ORed with any other flags you use.

Answer (score -1):

This [MSDN article about the CLSCTX enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693716%28VS.85%29.aspx) describes two values (CLSCTX_ACTIVATE_32_BIT_SERVER and CLSCTX_ACTIVATE_64_BIT_SERVER) with which a COM client can say its preference about the architecture of the COM server.

Instead of registering the running instance of my application both as 32 and 64 bit COM server, I could let the client express a preference about which version it wants to have so that Windows uses the running one. It is possible only under following conditions:

- The COM client can be modified,
- The COM client can detect which version (32 or 64 bit) of the out-of-process COM application is currently running.

*By the way the MSDN article explains quite well which version of Windows will prefer which version of the out-of-process COM component (Starting with Windows Server 2003 SP1, a 32 bit client prefers a 32 bit COM server).*